# How to create a multi-line plot for my dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, seaborn

I have the following pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Event1", "Event2", "Event3"], 
                                data=[[15,1,22],
                                      [16,1.26,80],
                                      [27,0,15]])

df = df.set_index([["Series1", "Series2", "Series3"]])
```

I want to create a multiline plot with the X axis containing `Event1`, `Event2` and `Event3`, while Y axis should be the corresponding numerical value. There should be 3 series: `Series1`, `Series2`, `Series3`.

How can I define `x`, `y` and `hue` in `sns.pointplot(x=???, y=???, hue=???,data=df)`?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = sns.pointplot(x=???, y=???, hue=???,data=df)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#d3d3d3', linewidth=1.0)
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#d3d3d3', linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is the aim to use `sns.pointplot` or to get the easiest way of obtaining the desired plot?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Ideally I'd like to use seaborn's `pointplot`. But I'd also accept pure `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reorganize df which is pivot table to classic data frame and plot as you want:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Event1", "Event2", "Event3"], 
                                data=[[15,1,22],
                                      [16,1.26,80],
                                      [27,0,15]])
df = df.set_index([["Series1", "Series2", "Series3"]])
print(df)

# reorganize df to classic table
df2=df.stack().reset_index()
df2.columns = ['Series','Event','Values']
print(df2)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = sns.pointplot(x='Event', y='Values', hue='Series',data=df2)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#d3d3d3', linewidth=1.0)
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#d3d3d3', linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

df2:

```
    Series   Event  Values
0  Series1  Event1   15.00
1  Series1  Event2    1.00
2  Series1  Event3   22.00
3  Series2  Event1   16.00
4  Series2  Event2    1.26
5  Series2  Event3   80.00
6  Series3  Event1   27.00
7  Series3  Event2    0.00
8  Series3  Event3   15.00
```

Comment: I have a dataframe and I want to plot counts for multiple years and months, this is great, thank you. `ax = sns.lineplot(x='month', y='Count', hue='year',data=Cov)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to do it with seaborn but with matplolib it's something like this:

```
for i in df.index.values:
    plt.plot(list(df.loc[i]))
plt.show()
```

In this case, the `X` ax will take value 0, 1 and 2 while the `Y` ax will take the value of your rows. Just do `plt.show()` at the end to have all plots in one figure. In seaborn should work pretty much in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method to obtain the desired plot is `df.T.plot()`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Event1", "Event2", "Event3"], 
                                data=[[15,1,22],
                                      [16,1.26,80],
                                      [27,0,15]])

df = df.set_index([["Series1", "Series2", "Series3"]])

df.T.plot()
```

[image]